# Can't retrieve more than one thread in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp

I wrote a small program for testing the OpenMP capabilities:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

    void main()
    {
        int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;

        omp_set_dynamic(0);
        omp_set_num_threads(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
        #pragma omp parallel
        {
            int id = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("hello %d\n", id);
        }
        getch();
    }
```

This program should output four lines, instead, I only get:

hello 0

as if there is only one active thread. Does anyone see any problem with my code.
(I work with visul studio 2015, windows 10)

Thanks in advance,
Jack.

Comment: did you activate the OpenMP support in your compiler? This is I believe done using the `/openmp` compiler option.

Comment: Make sure you've followed [what you need to do here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt15eb9t.aspx) to turn on OpenMP support.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot Gilles.